# how to work out $14^{293}-12^{26}\pmod{13}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How can I work this out without a calculator?

$$14^{293}-12^{26} \pmod{13}$$

I just couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$14\equiv 1\mod 13$ and $12\equiv -1\mod 13$

$14^{293}\equiv 1\mod 13$ and $12^{26}\equiv (-1)^{26}=1\mod 13$

$(14^{293}-12^{26})\equiv 0\mod 9$

Comment: So the powers dont matter at all?

Comment: So the answer would be 14^293 mod 13 - 12^26 mod 13 = 1 - 12 = -11? BUT that cant be right since the question also says the answer is less than 13 and is non negative

Comment: Yes the powes do matter If inplace of $26$ there was some odd integer then the conclusion woudn't have been true.

Comment: Over any field and for any natural $\;n\;$:$$1^n=1\;,\;\;(-1)^{2n}=1\ldots$$ Nice and simple answer. +1

Comment: ahh since -12 ^ even number would make it positive, meaning that it would be +12. How can 12^26 be equivelent to 1 mod 13? Won't it be 12 since mod is the remainder (ie 12)

Comment: $$12=-1\pmod{13}\implies 12^{26}=(-1)^{26}=1\pmod{13}\ldots$$

Comment: So is the answer 0?

Comment: So to sum it up I say (14^293 mod 13 ==> 1) + (-12^26 mod 13 ==> 12 or -1) (i use the -1 in this case since the question specifically asked for >13) 1 + -1 = 0.

Comment: Yes you are right its $0$. Yes your working is also correct.

Comment: Thanks! Did you mean mod 13 in the last line? Not mod 9. I can't seem to edit it.

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks

Comment: @Ghozt Yes mod 13 ....